# Plugin ABCPdf para de funcionar depois de qualquer deploy no SharePoint 2013

Tags: iis, sharepoint

Olá,
Estou com uma farm de SharePoint 2013 onde existe um servidor WFE e um servidor SAPP com uma base em um servidor compartilhado para outra farm. Recentemente venho enfrentando um problema com o componente ABCPdf (componente que gera pdfs das paginas do SharePoint), a cada deploy que realizo o componente para de funcionar necessitando que faça um IISRESET umas 2 vezes para funcionar novamente.

Alguém já enfrentou isso, ou algo parecido?

Pensei em no final de cada script de deploy acrescentar um comando para o IIS ser resetado uma ou duas vezes, porem há vezes que ele necessita de mais resets (alem de ser uma solução bem porca e errada para o problema).

Alguem teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: Que tipo de problema você esta enfrentando? Poderia adicionar mais informações?

Comment: Atualemte uso o ABCPlugin para 2 sites da minha Farm, porem a cada deploy de solução que faço ou a cada vez que reinicio o IIS não consigo mais fazer o download da pagina, me ele me da a exception que um erro inesperado aconteceu. depois que dou um Stop e Start nos sites ele volta a funcionar.